# Magento 2 : Submitting Order From Admin Silently Fails

Tags: admin, orders, error, magento2.2

I have a Magento 2.2, which has been migrated from Magento 1.

When I try to create an order from admin, the order submitting does not work. There is not error indicator whatsoever, also nothing in logs.

Searching the web I found a bug report https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2675 but this seems to be a different issue.

Looks like form validation fails somewhere but I have not been able to find out where.

I have tried with both Magento 2.2.0 and 2.2.2.

Any insight what might be root cause here?

Comment: check your browser console for any js issue

Comment: Nothing in the console, there seems to be no js or any other similar issues,  it looks like the form validation fails, but with no apparent reason and visible indicators.